# Alamofire in iOS is Receiving Dictionary Instead of Array

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am working on creating tables in iOS and am supposed to be receiving the required data in the form of JSON arrays. However, when I get the data in my iOS app it is presented as an unsorted dictionary instead. I was able to run the GET request in Postman and receive the data correctly, but when I receive it through Alamofire in my iOS app it is not formatted correctly. Is it possible that Alamofire would reformat the JSON somehow and convert all arrays to dictionaries, and can I override that setting somehow?

Here is an example of the column section of the JSON in Postman:

[image]

And here is what I am receiving through Alamofire:

[image]

This is how I am attempting to access the JSON

```
if let jsonColumns = json["columns"] as? [[String:Any]] {
        for columns in jsonColumns {
            for column in columns.values {
                if let c = column as? [String:Any] {
                    if c["isVisible"] as? Bool == false {
                        continue
                    }
                    if let columnName = c["name"] as? String {
                        dataSet.columns.append(columnName)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is dictionary. Value for columns is array.

Comment: I understand that, but if you look at the second image the value for columns is received as a dictionary instead of an array.

Comment: The value of `columns` in the second image is `[[String: Any]]` as well, it's just that the array is wrapped between parenthesis instead of square brackets.

Comment: If it is still an array, then why would the values be out of order?

Comment: show your code to decode the json

Comment: @ZacharyBell what are you calling to print out the alamofire data? are you using  `print()` for example?

Comment: Yes, I am using `print()`

Comment: @ZacharyBell, the `array` has just one element, which is `Dictionary`

Comment: Alamofire ObjectMapper order the parameters alphabetically. Can you change the JSON to be an Array of columns, like : {[{name: "1", visible: false},{name: "2", visible: false},{name: "3", visible: true}]} ? This way would solve the sorting problem.

Comment: @alxlives this is exactly what I was looking for. I didn't even realize the values were being ordered alphabetically.

Comment: Ok, I will post as an answer then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alamofire ObjectMapper order the parameters alphabetically.

You can change the JSON to be an Array of columns, like this:

```
 { "columns" : [ 
     {"name": "1", "visible": false},
     {"name": "2", "visible": false},
     {"name": "3", "visible": true}
]}
```

This way would solve the sorting problem.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the JSON in the 2 images are the same, you have `columns` that's an array of dictionaries (`[[String: Any]]`) that has only one element.

Values on the dictionary are not sorted because they are meant to be accessed by key and not by cycling through the values.

From [here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/CollectionTypes.html):

> A dictionary stores associations between keys of the same type and
>   values of the same type in a collection with no defined ordering. Each
>   value is associated with a unique key, which acts as an identifier for
>   that value within the dictionary. Unlike items in an array, items in a
>   dictionary do not have a specified order. You use a dictionary when
>   you need to look up values based on their identifier, in much the same
>   way that a real-world dictionary is used to look up the definition for
>   a particular word.

Comment: iterating through the content isn't the issue. It is the fact that the json I am receiving is not in the correct order.

Comment: You are using a wrong data structure. If you need the objects in some kind of sorting you should use an array and not a dictionary. The json object has the same access strategy as swift dictionary.

Comment: In other words, using a dictionary/json object there's not a "correct order" by definition.

Comment: @LorenzOliveto is right... i build a basic playground you can check to reproduce your problem: https://pastebin.com/S4pNmUgJ If you run it 3 times you most likely get diff results. and this is because how Dicts work.